# Create S3 folder alias or redirect url path to S3 folder

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to have an alias for a folder in S3 bucket?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I want to host a website with documentation of various projects and upload documentation for new versions of these projects to folders in S3 bucket.

Bucket content would be something like this:

```
<projectA>
|---<0.1.0>
    |---index.html
|---<0.2.0>
    |---index.html    
<projectB>
|---<1.0.0>
    |---index.html
|---<1.1.0>
    |---index.html
index.html
```

Now I'd like the newest version of any project to be aliased as 'latest'. So when I upload version 1.2.0 of projectB I remove alias 'latest' from version 1.1.0 and add the alias to newly uploaded '1.2.0'.

And url to index page of `projectB/1.2.0` would be `xxx.cloudfront.net/projectB/latest/index.html`

Is something like that even possible? Maybe with some redirects in cloudfront? (or route53)

Answer (score 3):

Two possible ways with CloudFront.

The easiest is to set up a CloudFront pointing at your bucket, and use the "Origin Path" value. In your example, you set Origin Path to `projectB/1.2.0` and call your distribution "latest.mydomain.com". When you update the files, go to origins and change the Origin path.

A more complex version is to use Lambda functions. Hook a lambda function to the "Origin Request" as that is specifically designed to rewrite URLs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html

Answer (score 2):

Worst case solution would be just *to have another folder in each project called as latest* and then whenever there is a new version of documentation release to any project, also *upload that index.html to latest folder as well* along with specific version folder.

Probably, have to *invalidate in CloudFront* for the origin path project /latest to make them effective immediately instead of waiting for TTL to invalidate the older cache.